# I think WLAN autoconfig can't find my wireless adapter

Tags: windows, drivers, wifi-driver, wireless-adapter

I have tried everything. The driver is installed and working but it won't show in network connections. WLAN autoconfig says everything is fine but it won't turn on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If it notebook, check Wireless not disabled by hardware switch or Fn+ hotkey.

On some notebooks when wireless disablen by hardware, adapter not detected.

Comment: I tried that it's not.